# Google Looker Studio simplest way to make line chart from aggregated monthly data

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, looker-studio

Having a little trouble figuring this out.

Data:

| Student ID | Sep Attendance | Oct Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 243156544 | 100 | 91 |
| 237831714 | 91 | 100 |
| 258358928 | 100 | 86 |

How would I create a line chart in Looker Studio like below?

[image]

So far I have tried with averaged fields, preprocessing data in BigQuery, and creating from a table within the Studio report (which I now don't think is possible). In Excel I would create a pivot chart and then a line pivot chart.

Any ideas? I am new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your data model. But first of all, in order to make sure that the order of the months are correct in the resulting diagram, rename your columns in your original table. Rename **Sep Attendance** to **September**, **Oct Attendance** to **October** and so on.

Now "unpivot" your table in BigQuery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <Your Table>
UNPIVOT(Attendance FOR Month IN (September, October))
```

Save the results as a new table. The new table will look like this:

| Student ID | Month | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 243156544 | September | 100 |
| 243156544 | October | 91 |
| 237831714 | September | 91 |
| 237831714 | October | 100 |
| 258358928 | September | 100 |
| 258358928 | October | 86 |

Now use this as your data source in looker studio. In the data source settings, make sure to set the type of **Month** Field to *"Date and Time > Month"*. Now add a line chart with this data source, set dimension to **Month** and Metric to **Attendance**. Click on the "SUM" icon next to the metric and set the aggregation method to *Average*. Now it will work as shown in your diagram.

Comment: I am getting a 'null' on the chart x axis when I set the data type to "Date and Time > Month". It works fine (albeit out of order) when as a string. Might you have any ideas?